# Core Graphics text is way faster than Core Text - I feel like I am missing something

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, core-text

Here's the code I use to show some text in core graphics:

```
int y = MESSAGE_FRAME.origin.y + 8;

if (month) y = y + 27;
int height = [JHomeViewCellContentView heightOfMessage:self.entry.message];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(MESSAGE_FRAME.origin.x + 8, y, MESSAGE_FRAME.size.width - 16, height);

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Crimson" size:15.0f];

[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:1.0] setFill];

[self.entry.message drawInRect:rect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

And here's the code if I want to show the same text in core text:

```
CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(MESSAGE_FRAME.origin.x + 8, self.bounds.size.height - y - height + 2, MESSAGE_FRAME.size.width - 16, height);


    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Crimson" size:15.0f];
    CGFloat lineHeight = [font lineHeight];

    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Crimson", 15.0f, NULL);

    CGFloat lineSpacing = 0;

    CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[] = {
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight, sizeof(lineHeight), &lineHeight },
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineSpacing, sizeof(lineSpacing), &lineSpacing },

    };

    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, sizeof(settings) / sizeof(settings[0]));

    NSMutableDictionary *attDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   (__bridge_transfer id)fontRef, (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                          paragraphStyle, kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                          nil];

     NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.entry.message attributes:attDictionary];

    //Flip the coordinate system
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);



    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, rect2);


    self.framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge_retained CFAttributedStringRef)attString);
    CTFrameRef theFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(self.framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [attString length]), path, NULL);

    CFRelease(path);

    CTFrameDraw(theFrame, context);
    CFRelease(theFrame);
```

Apparently, despite being more longwinded, core text is meant to be faster than core graphics, which is the reason I learnt how to do it. But running this code through in instruments, core graphics is achieving 5ms, while core text is doing it in 14ms. I feel like I am missing something here. drawInRect is almost 3 times faster, and I hear it should be slower. I've refined the code on the bottom as much as I know how to, but I am not an expert and I'd appreciate any help.

To clarify, I am drawing a block of text onto a view. That's all I wish to do. And all the text has the same appearance.

Comment: Core Text's strength is in text layout, and the underlying drawing code is implemented in Core Graphics, I don't see how it could be faster in simple text drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use the CT stuff, but it looks to me like you're setting up invariant font and other attributes on every draw.  Try factoring out everything up to the comment "Flip the coordinate system, and cache the attString.

That should improve speed for a better head-to-head test.

Comment: The problem is, although the attributes remain the same, the string itself changes every time. How would i cache it, when you can't set the string of a NSMutableAttributedString?

Comment: I see.  Hmm.  None of those attributes refer to the character level, so one idea would be to replace all the bytes in the mutable attributed string, but that does sound sketchy.  At the very least, you could cache attDictionary (most of the work is in there, anyway) and then alloc a new non-mutable attributed string each time.

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableAttributedString does let you change the string through
    replaceCharactersInRange:withString:

Once you've set the attributes dictionary, you can restrict further string updates to the attributed string via: 
    [myAttString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, myAttString.text.length) withString:newString]

and draw the dirty rect. Also, I've been finding that CGContextSetTextMatrix means little to nothing when using CTFrameDraw.

One other quick note, I don't see any releases on the CTFontRef and CTParagraphStyleRef. They also follow the "create rule" and need to be CFRelease()'d.

I've been struggling through my own Core Text learning curve(s) lately and seem to have achieved some promising results. I hope your own optimizations give you similar hope.